# Facebook Ads from Instagram in website analytics. UTM_source is showing facebook but uc_referrer and uc_last_referrer is showing Instagram

Tags: php, instagram, analytics, google-ads-api

Please help me I have get uc_referrer  http://instagram.com/ and uc_last_referrer  http://instagram.com/ and UTM_source is showing Facebook. Can you please tell me from where is user coming in my website?

Answer (score 0):

**UTM_source**:

UTM parameters in a URL identify the marketing campaign that refers traffic to a specific website. UTM_source specifically identifies which site sent the traffic, and is a required parameter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters

**Referer**:

I didn't find any documentation about uc_referrer or uc_last referrer, but `Referer` according to Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) refers to :

> the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed

So it seems like UTM_source is the advertiser traffic source. And referrer is the website link that a user is coming from, which is what you are looking for.